# Adding interconnected numbers to a drawing

Tags: drawing, microsoft-excel

For a SMED (single minute exchange of die) project I am working on I have to record the movements of persons on the shop floor to see if they are moving ineffeciently. I would like to do this by using a computer (to be able to undo and change the drawing), but I haven't found any programs capable of doing this easily. The thing I am looking for looks a bit like this:

[image: Example]

I want to be able to click somewhere and that a number appears, then I click on another place and the next number appears (= previous number + 1) interconnected by a arrow. Does such software exist?

P.S. I tried excel for making these kind of drawings, but I just works to slow for me.

Comment: You used Excel for this? Wow. I don't know of any software that does exactly what you want (with the autonumbering thing), but at least you can make drawing diagrams and graphs easier. My favorite for this purpose is yEd.

Comment: @John Y Once you know what you want, it is feasible in Excel.. I'll try yEd and come back to you. Is it possible to build a graph in yEd from an Excel table with tasks and locations at which the tasks are performed? So it can show which task is performed where?

Comment: @JohnY I built an adjacency matrix from my data and imported that in yed an it worked remarkably well! Thanks for your help!